# The dynamic link library for GLPK for Java could not be loaded

Tags: java, linear-programming, glpk

I am trying to use GLPK for my java project. I followed the link here https://wiki.nps.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=113606659 to install and config the GLPK for java. And in the java project, I used

```
compile 'org.gnu.glpk:glpk-java:1.12.0'
```

to include the glpk java project. Also, I copied the jar glpk-java-1.12.0.jar into the project lib folder, which was included by gradle as

```
flatDir {
   dirs 'lib'
}
```

Below is my testing code

```
public class ILPTest {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testGLPK();
    }

    private static void testGLPK() {
        System.out.println(GLPK.glp_version());
    }
}
```

However, when I ran it, I got the following error

```
The dynamic link library for GLPK for Java could not be loaded.
Consider using
java -Djava.library.path=
The current value of system property java.library.path is:
/Users/heya/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.

java.vendor: Oracle Corporation
java.version: 1.8.0_172
java.vm.name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.version: 25.172-b11
java.runtime.version: 1.8.0_172-b11
data model: 64 bit

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no glpk_java in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at org.gnu.glpk.GLPKJNI.<clinit>(GLPKJNI.java:29)
        at org.gnu.glpk.GLPK.glp_version(GLPK.java:2296)
        at com.ILPTest.testGLPK(ILPTest.java:46)
        at com.ILPTest.main(ILPTest.java:36)
```

what did I miss here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After I configure `-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib/jni` in IntelliJ, it works fine.